# How to add Column in Drupal's content View using VBO?

Tags: view, drupal-6, vbo

I want to add column into drupal's Content View.

In Drupal's admin panel, when we click on content Management-->Content-->List

the contents are loaded in table with columns **Title|Type|Author|Status|Operations**

I want add one more columns to this table and that is date and want to sort according to date.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't go through the trouble of altering that table. If you do so decide on going on that path here's a post that will help you: [Add column to content list](http://drupal.org/node/853580)

The easiest way to do this is to install the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module. Then

- add a new `node` type view
- add a `page` display
- **Fields** (After you add the fields you can put them in the desired order):

  - Node: Title
  - Node: Type
  - Note: Published (Status)
  - Node: Post date (Created)
  - User: Name (Author)
- **Sort criteria**

  - Node: Post date (Created)
- **Basic settings**

  - Style: Table
  - click the small settings (gear link next to it) and specify `Default sort` and which fields are `Sortable`.

You might have to do some small other tweaks for the view or fields. `Views` is a very powerful module and once you master it you can get just about any page you can image.

Comment: Mind you, the title of the question mentions VBO so it's pretty safe to assume the OP already has Views installed.

Comment: I am using OG on my website and I have added a column with the group to the table. The problem now is that' I can't select this column to be sortable in Basic Settings. Any clue for that?